# Website Language Translator messes up Header CSS

Tags: css, google-translate

I am using GOOGLE TRANSLATE plugin to use in my website but when a person visiting the website and changes the language e.g from English to French, the Header titles moves down.

I have used the GOOGLE TRANSLATE to test the translation but it do translates but the Header goes down due to a dropdown that appears and i have to close it each time i translate for the html page to be normal.

Try one Translate and see it guys and help me to solve this.

i am using a free hosting to test my website(index.html only) and 
my website is http://www.trialwebsite.comze.com/Index.html

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Please post your code, not a link to your site. You may wish to read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it is a long code that`s y i posted the link to the website so you all to try the translate and you can view source to see the code...

Comment: No, please let us see the relevant code in your question. Once you have fixed the site, the question will not longer make sense for future readers.